# include v-if directive inside v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an array called cars which I'm looping over using **v-for**.
I want to add a condition to that loop so if **color** property is equal to some value the system display a specific css style.

```
 <p v-for="car in cars" :key="car.color">
```

so the expected code would be like the following

if car.color == "red" execute class="style1" else if car.color == "green" class="style2"... and so on

Comment: I have read the doc but I can't apply v-if in v-for to get the expected @JaromandaX

Comment: @JaromandaX so impossible to get the desired output ?

Comment: actually, having read the question again, you don't even need to use a `v-if` you just need `:class="someFunction(car.color)"`

Comment: how to get child element of **v-for** to use it with **v-if**

Comment: As I said, `v-if` is actually not what you want anyway - sorry, I read the title and didn't read the body of the question properly

Answer (score 1):

What your describing is dynamic [class bindings](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html#binding-html-classes).

`v-if` is for conditional rendering, i.e. whether an element should be shown on the screen or not.

Using class bindings you can set a class, "style1" or "style2", etc. on an element based on some condition:

```html
  <p v-for="car in cars" :key="car.id" 
    :class="{ 
      style1: car.color === 'red',
      style2: car.color === 'blue'
    }">
    {{ car.name}}
  </p>
```

Or you can use a function, e.g. `:class="someFunction(car.color)"` (mentioned by Jaromanda X in his comment)

[Vue Playground example](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Using v-if with v-for is actually unrelated to your problem, but for future reference you can use both, just not on the same element.  The [Vue documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#v-for-with-v-if) mentions a solution:

> It's not recommended to use v-if and v-for on the same element due to implicit precedence

> This can be fixed by moving v-for to a wrapping  tag (which is also more explicit)

```html
<template v-for="todo in todos">
  <li v-if="!todo.isComplete">
    {{ todo.name }}
  </li>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use Dynamic Class Binding**

```
<p v-for="car in cars" :key="car.color" :class="getCarStyle(car.color)">
  {{ car.name }}
</p>
```

getCarStyle Method

```
getCarStyle(color) {
   if (color === "red") {
     return "style1";
   } else if (color === "green") {
     return "style2";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script setup>
    import { ref } from 'vue'

    const msg = ref('Hello World!')

    const cars = {
  carOne: {
    name: 'bmw',
    color: 'red',
  },
  caTwo: {
    name: 'Toyota',
    color: 'green',
  },
}
</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
  <input v-model="msg">

  <p v-for="car in cars" :key="car.color" :class="car.color"> {{ car.name }}</p>
</template>

<style scoped>
.red {
  color: red;
}

.green {
  color: green;
}
</style>
```